# Вопрос по функции sum в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
pr = [] # pr = profit

clients = [] # cl = clients

income = []

ifc = []

choice = None


while choice != "0":

print(
"""

0 - выйти.
1 - добавление клиентов в базу.
2 - расчитать налог и прибыль.
3 - посмотреть прошлые расчеты.
4 - список компаний
"""
)

choice = input ("Ваш выбор: ")

# заканчивает программу
print()
if choice == "0":

    print("до свидания.")

# добавление клиентов
elif choice == "1":

    print("Добавьте название компании")
    name = input("название компании: ")
    income = int(input("Доход от компании: "))
    company = (name, income)
    clients.append(company)
    ifc.append(income)

# начинается расчет налогов, и сохранение расчета.
elif choice == "2":
    ifc = (sum(income[:]))
    Employee_salary = input ("Зарплата сотрудника': ")
    Employee_salary = int(Employee_salary)

Employee_taxes = Employee_salary * 0.43
print ("\nНалог за сотрудника", Employee_taxes, "рублей")

tax = ifc * 0.06
print ("\nНалог равен", tax, "рублей")

profit = ifc - Employee_salary - Employee_taxes - tax
print ("\nПрибыль равна", profit, "рублей")
pr.append(profit)

# показывает прошлые расчеты

elif choice == "3":

    print("Прошлые расчеты")
    for profit in pr:
        print(profit, 'рублей')
        print (sum(pr))

# список клиентов на обслуживании
elif choice == "4":

    print("клиенты на обслуживании")

    for company in clients:
        name , income = company
        print (name, "\t" , income)

    for income in ifc:
        print (sum(ifc[:]))
```

Comment: Во-первых, если выбрать `2` не выбирая `1`, у вас не существует переменная `income`. Во-вторых, у вас `income` это одно число, как вы собираетесь его суммировать-то?

Comment: И не нужно писать `income[:]`, если не планируете от `income` получить копию списка в ней

Comment: income, это список, вот начало кода                                                         pr = []
clients = []                                                                                            
income = []
ifc = []
choice = None

Comment: @ИванКабенюк нет, у вас в строке `income = int(input("Доход от компании: "))` совершенно явно устанавливается число, а никакой не список

Comment: А то что в начале кода написано "income = []" разве не делает его пустым списком?

Comment: Делает, только вы этот пустой список потом уничтожаете, записывая вместо него это самое число

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое, понял. а не подскажите как можно решить задачу?

Comment: Я так и не понял что все эти переменные значат, но если вы хотите добавить число в список `income`, то используйте `income.append(тут нужное вам число)`

Comment: ниже напишу полный код, гляньте плиз

Comment: Не надо писать ниже, надо редактировать вопрос

Comment: А теперь вы стёрли сам вопрос

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения, я только тут зарегился)) отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Добавьте вопрос в сам вопрос. Поправьте форматирование кода.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `income` у вас типа `int`, для функции `sum` нужна коллекция элементов, типа `list`, `tuple`, `set`:

```
>>> sum([1, 3, 2, 3])
9
>>> sum({1, 3, 2, 3})
6
>>> sum((1, 3, 2, 3))
9
```

Из описания `sum`

```
>>> help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, start=0, /)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
    reject non-numeric types.
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что во втором случае получился 6?)

Comment: @andreymal Во втором случае используется множество (set), а оно исключает дупликаты :)

Comment: @andreymal А должно? 1+2+3=6